# How to pass parameters and receive response from a service task

Tags: jbpm

I've created a service task to call an internal web service in jbpm 6.0.1. Is there any documentation on how to pass parameters and receive the response from the web service?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the documentation link http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMDomainSpecificProcesses.html

You set your InputDataSet, OutputDataSet and Assignments like you do with other task types.

Comment: Not really. He is referring to the pre-canned Service Task, and there are some problems with this task (at least in 6.2 and 6.3) where it is not clear how to set up the output variables. The problem is compounded with the web-based designed - so significant bugs that forces you to run jbpm with -Ddesigner.useolddataassignments=true